Why does the continuous homomorphism group equal the homomorphism group?
I have the following question on Silverman's book The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, 2nd edition.
First, let $K$ be a perfect field, $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ be the absolute Galois group of $K$, and $M$ be a continuous $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ module. In Remark 2.2 on p.419 in Appendix B.2, we see that if $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ acts trivially on $M$, then $$H^1(G_{\overline{K}/K},M)=\text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(G_{\overline{K}/K},M).$$
Now, let $K$ be a number field, $E/K$ be an elliptic curve, and $m\ge 2$ be an integer. In VIII.2 on p. 216, it was claimed that
$$H^1(G_{\overline{K}/K},E[m])=\text{Hom}(G_{\overline{K}/K},E[m]).$$
I am wondering why $$\text{Hom}(G_{\overline{K}/K},E[m])=\text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(G_{\overline{K}/K},E[m])$$ in this case?

I don't think this is true; I think you can safely assume Silverman means continuous homomorphisms here.

The answer to this is that they are never equal outside of trivial cases, and Silverman had a typo in it.
This is not obvious, indeed if $K$ is a local field, then
$\text{Hom}(G_{\bar K/K},A)=\text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(G_{\bar K/K},A)$
for any finite abelian group $A$. I sketch an argument for this at the end of this answer.
However, for number fields $K$, we should in general expect $\text{Hom}(G_{\bar K/K},A)\neq \text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(G_{\bar K/K},A)$. In fact, they are not equal for any number field $K$ and any abelian group $A$. We will show this in the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ However, before we do that we introduce some generalities on profinite groups.
Let $G$ be a profinite group, and let $f:G\to A$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to a discrete topological group. I claim that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\text{ker}(f)$ is open.
Suppose $f$ is continuous. If $0$ is the identity in $A$, then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be open because $\{0\}$ is open. But $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\text{ker}(f)$, so we are done in this case.
Now if $\text{ker}(f)$ is open, then for $a\in A$, $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\tilde{a}\text{ker}(f)$ for some preimage of $a$ in $G$. (If no such preimage exists, then $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is open because it is empty.) We see that $\tilde{a}\text{ker}(f)$ is open because multiplication by $\tilde{a}$ is continuous and $\text{ker}(f)$ is open by assumption. Since all preimages of singletons are open, $f$ is continuous.
With this established, we now return to the original problem. Define
$$L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,...)$$
Note that $H=\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\aleph_0}$ by an inverse limit argument. Now, $H$ is an uncountable $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space, which means it has an uncountable basis $\{g_i\}_{i\in I}$. (Note that $\{(1,0,...),(0,1,0,...)\}$ is not a basis because it misses $(1,1,1,...)$.) In particular, we have obtained uncountably many subgroups
$$\{H_i\}_{i\in I}=\text{Span}\{g_j\}_{j\in I,j\neq i}$$
However, there are only countably many finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. By infinite Galois theory and the pidgeonhole principle, this implies that at least one of the $H_i$ is not open, say $H_{\alpha}$. Let $G_{\alpha}$ be the preimage of $H_{\alpha}$ in $G_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}}$, then we once again see by infinite Galois theory that $G_{\alpha}$ is not open. It follows that there are non-continuous elements of $\text{Hom}(G_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, in particular quotienting by $G_{\alpha}$.
I will briefly touch on how to do this for arbitrary $A$ and $K$. First, you reduce to the case of $A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then, you must construct an extension $L/K$ with Galois group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\aleph_0}$. To do this, you can construct such an extension $\mathbb{Q}^{(p)}/\mathbb{Q}$ for $\mathbb{Q}$ using a cyclotomic field argument, and then consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}^{(p)}K/K$.

One reason that $\text{Hom}(G_{\bar K/K},A)=\text{Hom}_{\text{cont}}(G_{\bar K/K},A)$ for local fields $K$ comes from a result of Nikolov and Segal that all finite index subgroups of finitely generated profinite groups are open, combined with the fact that absolute Galois groups of local fields are finitely generated. (This second theorem is not obvious, but not as difficult as the first. The content of Ch. 7 of Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch, Schmidt, and Wingberg would suffice.)
